# Can you use a variable in the [limit (x)] option of the cumulative predicate in prolog?

Tags: prolog, scheduling, swi-prolog, constraint-programming, clpfd

I simply want to do something like this

```
schedule(Activities, GLB) :-

    get_start_times(Activities,StartTimes),
    get_resources(Activities,Resources),
    get_durations(Activities,Durations),

    sum_list(Durations, MaxTime),
    StartTimes ins 0..MaxTime,
    GLB in 0..100,
    get_tasks(StartTimes,Durations,Resources, Tasks),
    cumulative(Tasks, [limit(GLB)]),

    labeling([min(GLB)],[StartTimes, GLB]).
```

I want to retrieve schedules of activities ordered by the minimization of the global resource limit which is an option of the cumulative predicate. But I keep getting arguments not sufficiently instantiated when trying to give the limit as a variable. If it is indeed not possible what other way can I achieve what I want ?

Comment: Enumerate `GLB` yourself. Prior to `cumulative/2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only repeat what `false` already said: You can enumerate `GLB` yourself, so that it is instantiated when `cumulative/2` is posted. It is currently not possible to specify a variable as a resource limit.

You are on the right track, simply change the final portion of your predicate to:

```
StartTimes ins 0..MaxTime,
GLB in 0..100,
get_tasks(StartTimes,Durations,Resources, Tasks),
indomain(GLB),
cumulative(Tasks, [limit(GLB)]),
labeling([], StartTimes).
```

Using `indomain/1` will enumerate all possible instantiations of `GLB` to concrete integers, in ascending order. So, this gives you iterative deepening and will succeed for the smallest value of `GLB` that is admissible.